# Pass by reference for array of objects

Tags: c++

I m working in a class called Employee and I m trying to create a constructor that takes an array as a parameter

```
class Employee 
{ 
Employee * array[9];
public:
Employee(Employee * arr[]);
}
```

But this wouldn't work, so I m thinking of passing by reference the `arr`, except I can't just add & before the `arr`... Any Ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Use `std::vector`. /end thread

Comment: "...that takes an array as a parameter." An array of *what*?? Your member is array of pointers, while you're parameter is a simple pointer (assuming you fixed the outright syntax error of the closing `]`). Your question is unclear at best.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work? Arrays are passed by reference *by default.* But do Employee objects really have arrays of Employee objects as members? Are you sure your design is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to pass an array of type Employee, then you do

`Employee (Employee arr[])`
 or 
`Employee (Employee * arr)`

If you want to pass it an array of POINTERS to Employee objects then you do

`Employee (Employee * arr[])`
or 
`Employee (Employee ** arr)`

These all will work.

Also, arrays are always passed by reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to pass in an array, you'll also need to pass in the size:

```
class Employee
{
public:
    Employee(Employee* pE, std::size_t size) { ... }
};
```

Since you'll be demoting the array to a pointer, and will otherwise have no idea as to the size.  As you are passing the pointer, there is no need for it to be passed by reference as you can change the value of the elements and it will be pointing to the same memory location (that is, it would be no different than passing by reference).

It would be a better solution to use either `std::array` or `std::vector`, though:

```
class Employee
{
public:
    Employee(const std::vector<Employee>& vec) { ... }
};
```

Side note:  I'm not sure why you have an Employee object that takes an array of Employees to construct it.  That seems to be a sign of a design issue.